# Can an iPhone app send a command (data) through Wi-Fi (or maybe Bluetooth) to a device at a specific time when it is not running through?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Situation: My iPhone communicates to an external device through Wi-Fi. The app has also the ability to set up a schedule. This means that on a specific time the device should turn on and do some stuff. Now for this to happen there should be a timer on the external device or the iPhone should send a command to the device on a specific time.

Question: Is it possible to send a command to the external device while the app is in the background? Or does the app have to be in the foreground? Is it possible when the external device is an accesory? Cause I have read that apps are allowed to run in the background when they need to communicate to accessories??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do this, you are only able to run an app in the background if its stream audio, a VOIP client or track user location. If you are in the accessories program (which means you can make hardware that works with the dock connector, then your app can also run in the background. but only if the accessories that is respons to is connected.

There is no way the schedule any operation to be triggered at a set time.

You can schedule a local notification, but the user wil have to view (open you app by click in the notification) before you app get informed about it.

Comment: Well Apple states that an accessory that uses Bluetooth can have the ability to run for a long time in the background doesn't it? See [App states and multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)

Comment: I really can not comment on that, I've never done any thing like that.

Comment: Ok, the main point was actually Wi-Fi, I alrady thought that it is not possible, but I was doubting on a major point and that was: iDevice accessory, apparently a device is only an accessory when a device communicates through Bluetooth or the 30 pin connector

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have the devices communicating? If not, you should take a look at Apple's MFI (Made for iPhone) program. Sending data or communicating from your iPhone to an external accessory through bluetooth falls under it. They provide you with certain protocol specifications that allow you to communicate with external accessories. It's difficult to do something like this if you are an individual developer though. Here's the link: https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/.